# Validation of a date in a tkinter entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

hi i want to make sure that a user can only type a date into an entry box. i am familiar with wildcard searches in a database therefore i tried this;

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()

def Validate():
    if Entry1.get() == ('**/**/****'):
        window2=Tk()
        label2= Label(window2,text = 'Successful')
        label2.pack()
    else:
        window3=Tk()
        label3 = Label(window3,text = 'Failed')
        label3.pack()

Entry1 = Entry(window)
Entry1.pack()


label1 = Label(window, text = "Please enter date")
label1.pack()

submitbutton = Button(window, text = "Submit")
submitbutton.pack()

submitbutton.configure(command=Validate)
```

But obviously this doesn't work, any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Define what you believe to be a valid date. It sounds stupid, but it can vary.

Comment: any date where there has 2 digits for day, 2 for month and 2 for year, or a date which isnt't in the future if thats not too hard?

Comment: is `99/99/13` a valid date? It has 2/2/2 digits, and doesn't occur in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real validation, it's going to take a little more work than one line. You want two things: number of digits and an actual date in the past. For the number of digits, I'd `split()` the user's date string into a list, then iterate through each item checking that each is 1) an integer, and 2) has a `len()` of 2.

After validating that it's in the format of a date, you can check that it's a previously existing date with Python's `time` module (http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/time.html). In this example, `systemDate` is the current time in a `struct_time` object, and you can set the userDate to the same type of object with the `strptime` function for a comparison check:

```
>>> from time import strptime, struct_time, localtime
>>> systemDate = struct_time(localtime())
>>> userDate = strptime('01/02/03', '%m/%d/%y')
>>> userDate < systemDate
True
```

Hope that helps.